# Accessing Firebase value

Tags: node.js, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with a simple JSON from Firebase and I am trying to access the value inside it. But can't seems to wrap my head around, I am trying to access the apiHash and apiId. Any help will be great! Thanks

This is the json retuned by Firebase.

```
Mv9ALVaVEwa0nGyYWeo:{
apiHash: '6962d35961356a5', 
apiId: 9506201
}
```

The code to get the json above

```
async function queryData(_mobileNo){
  const ref  = admin.database().ref("users/");
  const snapshot = await ref.orderByChild("mobileNo").equalTo(_mobileNo).once('value');
  return snapshot.val();
}
```

The Firebase realtime data structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) as shown below:

```js
// data = snapshot.val()
const data = {
  randomKey: {
    apiHash: "value"
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(data)[0]);
```